# How to get this main parameter on Express Node.js

Tags: node.js, parameters, routes

On Express Node.js, I have a code like this :

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const testController = require("./Controllers/TestController");

app.use("/:isoLang/test", testController(router));
```

How to can I get the value of `isoLang` parameter from `TestController.js` ?

*PS :*

- This kind of resources don't help me : [Routage Express.js](https://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html)
- Sorry if this question is already asked but I don't found a similar question
- From `TestController.js`, I have tried `const isoLang = request.params.isoLang;` but it is undefined
- I already inspected the whole `request` object (from `TestController.js`) but it doesn't contain `isoLang`

---

**Update :** 
As answered below, the solution is to set the router to : `express.Router({ mergeParams: true })` 
Hope that it help other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to pass { mergeParams: true } to your router contsructor, so you can access all through req.params

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const controllers = (router) => {
  router.get("/:param2/", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params);
    res.send('ok')
  })

  return router;
};

app.use("/:isoLang/test", controllers(express.Router({ mergeParams: true })));

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("service is ready on port 8080");
});
```

see [Router API docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.router)

Comment: Thank you, it works. The tip is : express.Router({ mergeParams: true })